# Normalize date format in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark, transformation

I have a dataframe that contains 3 different patterns of date - 1/1/90, 1-1-1990, 1/1/1990. I am trying to normalize these into 1-1-1990. I am able to convert 1/1/90 and 1-1-1990 using the following function, but how to handle 1/1/1990 within the same function.

```
df = df.withColumn("date", to_date(df.x, "M-d-y"))
df = df.withColumn(
    "better_date",
    when(year(df.date) < 24, add_months(df.date, 12 * 2000))
    .when(year(df.date) < 1000, add_months(df.date, 12 * 1900))
    .otherwise(df.date),
)
```